# I wrote a simple program of rock paper scissors, but I want to make a best out of three and have no idea how I could write it into my existing code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just like the title suggests, I am new and trying to hone my skills but I have no idea how to go about this... any help would be appreciated.

```
import random

playerOneWin = ((1,3), (3,2), (2,1))
playerTwoWin = ((3,1), (2,3), (1,2))
tie = ((1,1), (2,2), (3,3))



while True:
    roll = random.randint(1,3), random.randint(1,3)
    if roll in tie:
        print('Tie')
        break
    elif roll in playerOneWin:
       print('Player 1 Wins')
       break
    elif roll in playerTwoWin:
       print('Player 2 Wins')
       break
```

Like do I make a function? Do I write it in to my while loop?

and if I do then how? How would I even go about it?

Comment: @Sid: Those are tuples. They're like lists, but immutable. Using a `set` for the outer elements might be even better, e.g. `playerOneWin = {(1,3), (3,2), (2,1)}`.

Comment: @Blckknght Thank you, thats what I will do...

Answer (score 1):

General Advice on problem-solving:

- Think about what the general solution is, and refine to an algorithm instead of listing all possible outcomes.

To fulfill "best of 3", meaning 2-0 stops after 2 executions, check for a score of 2 from either player and end there.

There can, of course, be further optimizations, but this introduces a few concepts. Namely: functions, dictionaries, if statements, f-strings, and *args as function arguments.

I decided to show some additional information at the bottom that includes total games played and the number of ties.

```
import random

def winner(p1, p2):
    return (3 + p1 - p2) % 3

def score_round():
    roll = random.randint(1,3), random.randint(1,3)
    w = winner(*roll)
    if w == 0:
        scores[w] += 1
        print('Tie')
        return
    scores[w] += 1
    print(f"Player {w} Wins")
    return

num_games = 3
games_to_win = num_games // 2 + 1
games_played = 0
scores = {0:0, 1:0, 2:0}
while True:
    score_round()
    games_played += 1
    if scores[1] == games_to_win or scores[2] == games_to_win:
        break

if scores[1] > scores[2]: print(f"Player 1 wins: {scores[1]} - {scores[2]}")
else: print(f"Player 2 wins: {scores[2]} - {scores[1]}")
print(f"Games played: {games_played}, Ties: {scores[0]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize 2 counter variables that will track the number of wins each player has. Increment each player's respective win count by 1 when they win a round. Ties should not increment either counter.

And instead of doing `while True:`, you can use something like

```
while p1Wins < 2 or p2Wins < 2:

# rest of your code
```

And of course, with the proper conditional in the `while` loop, you can also remove those `break` statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def best_of(x):
    playerOneWin = ((1,3), (3,2), (2,1))
    playerTwoWin = ((3,1), (2,3), (1,2))
    tie = ((1,1), (2,2), (3,3))


    i=0
    while True:
        roll = random.randint(1,3), random.randint(1,3)
        if roll in tie:
            print('Tie')
        elif roll in playerOneWin:
            print('Player 1 Wins')
        elif roll in playerTwoWin:
            print('Player 2 Wins')
        i=i+1
        if i==x:
            break
```

Run the function as best_of(3) or best_of(5)....

Comment: I didn't realize you wanted a function. Code updated, check it now.

Comment: I don't need a function specifically, I just wanted to know the most efficient way of doing this and yours by far is my favorite. Thank you....

Comment: Then please consider upvoting & accepting it as answer.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your code and requirement as suggested in the title,
You can make change in your existing to work as function and following code:

```
def rps(best_of_n=3):
    player1_win = 0
    player2_win = 0
    while best_of_n>0:
        best_of_n = best_of_n - 1
        roll = random.randint(1,3), random.randint(1,3)
        if roll in tie:
            print('Tie')
        elif roll in playerOneWin:
            player1_win = player1_win + 1
            print('Player 1 Wins')
        elif roll in playerTwoWin:
            player2_win = player2_win + 1
            print('Player 2 Wins')
    if player2_win > player1_win:
        print('player 2 win the game')
    else:
        print('player 1 win the game.')
```

Or if you want to modify the while loop then just do following:

```
n = 3
while n>0:
    n = n - 1
    roll = random.randint(1,3), random.randint(1,3)
    if roll in tie:
        print('Tie')
    elif roll in playerOneWin:
        player1_win = player1_win + 1
        print('Player 1 Wins')
    elif roll in playerTwoWin:
        player2_win = player2_win + 1
        print('Player 2 Wins')
if player2_win > player1_win:
    print('player 2 win the game')
else:
    print('player 1 win the game.')
```

Comment: Usually in a "best of X" series you can stop early once one side has won more than `X/2` games. This code always runs all `X`.

Answer (score -1):

```py
import random

bestof3 = []
playerOneWin = [[1,3], [3,2], [2,1]]
playerTwoWin = [[3,1], [2,3], [1,2]]
tie = [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]]
rolllist = []
counter = 3
while counter > 0:
    rolllist.append(random.randint(1,3))
    rolllist.append(random.randint(1,3))
    if rolllist in tie:
        print('Tie')
    elif rolllist in playerOneWin:
       print('Player 1 Wins')
       counter -= 1
       bestof3.append('P1')
    elif rolllist in playerTwoWin:
       print('Player 2 Wins')
       counter -= 1
       bestof3.append('P2')
    rollist.clear()
p1 = bestof3.count('P1')
p2 = bestof3.count('P2')
if p1 > p2: print('Player one wins the game')
else: print('Player 2 wins the game')
```

I have tried to keep code simple.This makes a list of what Players one and two have won(bestof3) and keeps appending either `'P1'` or `'P2'` depending on who wins. And in the end, the lists are evaluated and you get your answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
player1 = 0 
player2 = 0 
if player1 >= 2:
    print('Player 1 Wins best out of 3')
    break
elif player2 >= 2:
    print('Player 2 Wins best out of 3')
    break
```